# Convert Python Json.dump with headers and values in columns

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I am importing data to a json file , but when I convert it to csv with pandas , it is only getting grouped by {} i also need the data in the group filed to be added to an individual column this is what I am currently getting [{"RegistrationDetails": {"Mark": "ERDW", "PreviousID": "PH-UGW", "Status": "Registered", "CurrentRegistrationDate": "11-Nov-2013", "DeRegistrationDate": null, "Reason": null, "To": null}, "RegistrationHistory": [{"RegistrationMark": "ERDW", "IssueDate": "11-Nov-2013", "EndDate": null, "Reference": "G-ERDW/R1", "Notes": " ", "OwnershipStatus": "Owned", "RegisteredAircraftOwners": [{"RegisteredOwner": "GERHARD WOLFSHOHL", "AddressIndicatorID": 1, "AddressIndicator": "", "TradingAs": null, "TrusteeOf": null, "Address1": "ENGLANDSWEG 14", "Address2": null, "Town": "NEUBOERGER", "County": null, "PostCode": null, "Country": "GERMANY"}], "HistoricalLedgerDocs": [], "IssueDateRaw": "2013-11-11T08:47:29"}], "AircraftDetails": {"Manufacturer": "ENSTROM HELICOPTER CORPORATION", "Type": "ENSTROM F-28F", "SerialNumber": "784", "ICAO24BitAircraftAddress": {"Binary": "0100_0000_0110_1010_1000_1010", "Hex": "406A8A", "Octal": "20065212"}, "PopularName": "FALCON", "ICAOAircraftTypeDesignator": "EN28", "AircraftClass": "HELICOPTER", "BuildCategory": null, "EasaCategory": "CS-27 : Small Rotorcraft", "Engines": [{"NumberOfEngines": 1, "Name": "LYCOMING HIO-360-F1AD ", "TotalNumberOfEngines": 1, "IsPropeller": false}], "Mtow": "1179 kg", "TotalAirframeHours": "3500 at 23-Sep-2018", "YearBuild": 1992, "MaintenanceProgramme": "MP/04119/P", "Expiry": null, "OwnershipStatus": "Owned", "MaximumPassengers": "2", "MaximumTakeOffMass": "1179", "CofaDetails": {"CofaCategory": "EASA Certificate of Airworthiness", "CofaValidityExpiryLabel": "EASA ARC Expiry:", "CofaValidityExpiry": "22-Sep-2020", "CofaValidityReference": "G-ERDW/DE.MG.1052/23092019", "CofaOperatingLimitations": null, "ShowOperatingLimitations": false}, "IsPotentialChangeOfOwnership": false}, "MortgageDetails": [], "RegisteredAircraftOwners": [{"RegisteredOwner": "GERHARD WOLFSHOHL", "AddressIndicatorID": 1, "AddressIndicator": "", "TradingAs": null, "TrusteeOf": null, "Address1": "ENGLANDSWEG 14", "Address2": null, "Town": "NEUBOERGER", "County": null, "PostCode": null, "Country": "GERMANY"}], "AircraftOperatedByAocHolder": {"showSection": false, "OperatorName": null, "OperatorTrandingAs": null}, "InsuranceSummaryDetails": {"EvidenceVerifiedDate": "20-Feb-2018", "NoFlyDate": null, "AircraftMarkStatusID": 1, "AircraftID": 66608, "Mark": "ERDW"}, "NoiseSummaryDetails": {"NoiseCertificateIssueDate": "13-Dec-2013", "NoiseCertificateNumber": "023577", "NoiseChapter": "11"}, "RegistrationMarkExemption": null, "OpenRegistrationCases": [], "OpenApplicationsAndApprovalsCases": [], "ExtractDate": "11-Feb-2020 21:03"}, {"RegistrationDetails": {"Mark": "PAOL", "PreviousID": "D-CPAO", "Status": "De-registered", "CurrentRegistrationDate": "21-Mar-2013", "DeRegistrationDate": "06-Mar-2019", "Reason": "Transferred to another country or authority", "To": "UNITED STATES OF AMERICA"}, "RegistrationHistory": [{"RegistrationMark": "PAOL", "IssueDate": "21-Mar-2013", "EndDate": "06-Mar-2019", "Reference": "G-PAOL/R1", "Notes": "Transferred to another country or authority UNITED STATES OF AMERICA", "OwnershipStatus": "Chartered", "RegisteredAircraftOwners": [{"RegisteredOwner": "BLU HALKIN LTD", "AddressIndicatorID": 1, "AddressIndicator": "", "TradingAs": null, "TrusteeOf": null, "Address1": "7 TORRIANO MEWS", "Address2": null, "Town": "LONDON", "County": null, "PostCode": "NW5 2RZ", "Country": "UNITED KINGDOM"}], "HistoricalLedgerDocs": [], "IssueDateRaw": "2013-03-21T11:44:54"}], "AircraftDetails": {"Manufacturer": "CESSNA AIRCRAFT COMPANY", "Type": "CESSNA 525B", "SerialNumber": "525B-0232", "ICAO24BitAircraftAddress": {"Binary": "0100_0000_0110_1001_0101_1101", "Hex": "40695D", "Octal": "20064535"}, "PopularName": "CITATIONJET CJ3", "ICAOAircraftTypeDesignator": "C25B", "AircraftClass": "FIXED-WING LANDPLANE", "BuildCategory": null, "EasaCategory": "CS-23D : Commuter Category Aeroplane", "Engines": [{"NumberOfEngines": 2, "Name": "WILLIAMS INTERNATIONAL FJ44-3A ", "TotalNumberOfEngines": 2, "IsPropeller": false}], "Mtow": "6291 kg", "TotalAirframeHours": "3060 at 08-Feb-2019", "YearBuild": 2008, "MaintenanceProgramme": "None", "Expiry": null, "OwnershipStatus": "Chartered", "MaximumPassengers": "8", "MaximumTakeOffMass": "6291", "CofaDetails": {"CofaCategory": "Revoked", "CofaValidityExpiryLabel": "EASA ARC Expiry:", "CofaValidityExpiry": "", "CofaValidityReference": "G-PAOL/UK.MG.0663/20122016", "CofaOperatingLimitations": null, "ShowOperatingLimitations": false}, "IsPotentialChangeOfOwnership": false}, "MortgageDetails": [], "RegisteredAircraftOwners": [{"RegisteredOwner": "BLU HALKIN LTD", "AddressIndicatorID": 1, "AddressIndicator": "", "TradingAs": null, "TrusteeOf": null, "Address1": "7 TORRIANO MEWS", "Address2": null, "Town": "LONDON", "County": null, "PostCode": "NW5 2RZ", "Country": "UNITED KINGDOM"}], "AircraftOperatedByAocHolder": {"showSection": false, "OperatorName": null, "OperatorTrandingAs": null}, "InsuranceSummaryDetails": {"EvidenceVerifiedDate": "25-Feb-2019", "NoFlyDate": null, "AircraftMarkStatusID": 2, "AircraftID": 66252, "Mark": "PAOL"}, "NoiseSummaryDetails": {"NoiseCertificateIssueDate": "22-Mar-2013", "NoiseCertificateNumber": "023196", "NoiseChapter": "03"}, "RegistrationMarkExemption": null, "OpenRegistrationCases": [], "OpenApplicationsAndApprovalsCases": [], "ExtractDate": "11-Feb-2020 21:03"},
I would need Column header Manufacturer , row ENSTROM HELICOPTER CORPORATION , Column Header Type - row ENSTROM F-28F , Column Header Serial Number , row 784 etc

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: pd.read_json(json.dumps(x).to_csv('Register'))

Comment: Try `pd.read_json(json.dumps(x)).to_csv('Register')` did you get an error with your current code?

Comment: sorry , i posted the code with the error , this code adds a column for RegistrationDetails and the has all the data stored in that column , until next column -  AircraftOperatedByAocHolder , then same upto next column ExtractDate , InsuranceSummaryDetails , MortgageDetails , NoiseSummaryDetails etc. I dont need those as columns , I need the data between them as columns , these appear to be group columns